# Is there a term for people on the same line of the family tree?

Tags: kinship-terms

I accidentally confused "generation" and this a long time ago, but now I'm curious.

If two people are both 1st cousins, they are on the same line.

siblings? (or half, or just, 1Qth cousin that is only related to you from the beginning of time)

If you write your WHOLE family tree, and write it organized on ruled paper, the people I am referring to are on the same line.

Comment: Your second, third, fourth, etc. cousins are also ask of the same generation as your first cousins.

Comment: If you mean a horizontal line, the term "once removed" is used for cousins on a different "line". So your 2nd cousin's parent is your second cousin once removed. If you mean a vertical line, I believe "lineage" (see the line inside) is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation#Familial_generation) is exactly the word you want.

> A familial generation is a group of living beings constituting a single step in the line of descent from an ancestor

This can be very different from the meaning "a group of people living at the same time" and often was when people had larger families over more years.  But it is one meaning of the term, and the only one I have heard of.

Comment: For instance, all of my grandparents are on the same (horizontal) line of my family tree. But they have no relation to each other, except a generational one.

Comment: I agree that *generation* is the right word, noting though that there are some cases where a person can belong to two generations within their family tree (e.g., if their parents were cousins once removed).